# Error : "could not open session" when switch to non root user inside docker container from root user using su command

Tags: linux, docker

I am not able to switch to non root user inside docker container from root user using su command.

Following is what I did

1. I created a docker container on centos:6
2. created a user "circa" inside container
3. updated /etc/security/limits.conf file with below data in container

   circa        hard    nofile  5000

   circa        soft    nofile  5000
4. But when I switch to user "circa" using command "su - circa", I get error

   "could not open session"

If I reduce the nofile count to around "4000", I can login as circa user using command "su - circa" and run my server program.

What do I need to do make it work for higher nofile count numbers ?

Some details about my environment :

Docker Host information

```
#kernel version
# uname -r
3.10.81-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64

#os release
# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
```

Docker Container information

```
#os release
# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)

#kernel version
# uname -r
3.10.81-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64
```

Comment: So how about the `USER circa` in Dockerfile?

Comment: thanks I did not pay attention to this Dockerfile directive before, this seems to be useful. However right now I cannot use it for my current need.